# Disable Typewatch binding when Enter key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, typewatch

I am using `Typewatch` jQuery plugin in one of the applications and I have the following code for submitting the form and calling an Ajax request.'

```
searchForm.on('submit', function(event) {
    if (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    if (search.data.searchRequest) {
        search.data.searchRequest.abort();
    }
    searchForm.addClass('is-loading');
    search.data['searchStart'] = 0;
    $('#js-postslist--searchpanel').empty();
    $('.js-searchpanel-results').removeClass('is-visible');
    var filterQuery = csUtils.methods.getFilterQuery(true, search.data.terms);
    search.data.searchRequest = search.methods.ajaxCloudSearch(filterQuery);
});

searchField.typeWatch({
    callback: function() {
        return searchForm.submit();
    },
    wait: 500,
    highlight: false
});
```

Here the issue is, when I press `Enter`(return) key, the form is getting submitted twice. It is going to the submit function two times as the form has default submit behavior on pressing the `Enter` key. I can't remove this as users will press the key once they enter the search term.  I need to disable the Typewatch binding when `Enter` key is pressed so it will not submit the form two times.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept the `keydown` event on the input element. If its the enter key call `preventDefault` to stop the form from submitting. The callback will be fired immediately because TypeWatch triggers the callback on enter key.

```js
searchField.on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (typeof e.keyCode !== 'undefined' && e.keyCode === 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  })
  .typeWatch({
    callback: function(value) { console.log(value); },
    wait: 500
  });
```

You can see a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/tbg7a84k/18/ (try commenting out the preventDefault call and you'll see that it submits the form).

There may be some value in TypeWatch returning the reason the callback was triggered, perhaps the callback could send a reason: `ENTER_KEY` or `ELAPSED` then in the callback you could simply check `if reason === 'ENTER_KEY'` (pull request welcome).